# How can I avoid ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection errors in my setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models in my rails app:

```
class SaleContact < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :key_contact_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :sales_opportunity_id, message: "Contact already added!" }
 validates :sales_opportunity_id, presence: true
 belongs_to :key_contact, inverse_of: :sale_contacts
 belongs_to :sales_opportunity, inverse_of: :sale_contacts
 has_many :phone_numbers, :through => :key_contact
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_numbers
end
```

I'm trying to create a sale_contact from the sales_opportunity screen by selecting a key_contact (assume a key_contact already exists). I would also like the ability to add a phone_number at the same time using fields_for and nested attributes.

```
class KeyContact < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :first_name, :last_name, :company_id, presence: true
 has_many :phone_numbers, dependent: :destroy
 belongs_to :company
 has_many :sales_opportunities, :through => :sale_contacts
 has_many :sale_contacts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Assume I've already created the key_contact and assigned it to the company that owns it.

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :number, :key_contact_id, presence: true
 belongs_to :key_contact
end
```

Nothing magical here - just a very basic model for a phone number.

On the sales_opportunity page I can load a modal that adds a new sale_contact. It's a bootstrap modal loaded by AJAX, but I don't think that matters much (I've only included the form parts for brevity):

```
<%= form_for(@sale_contact, :html => {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'sale_contact'}, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <% if @sale_contact.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@sale_contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this sale_contact from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @sale_contact.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="form-group" id= "contact_error">
        <%= f.label :key_contact_id, :class => "control-label" %>
        <div id="contact_select">
        <%= f.collection_select :key_contact_id, @sales_opportunity.company.key_contacts(:full_name), :id, :full_name %>
        </div>
        <span class="warning-block"></span>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
      </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :role, :class => "control-label" %>
          </br>
            <%= f.select(:role, options_for_select(@roles.collect { |r| [r[0].humanize, r[0]] }, selected: @sale_contact.role), {}) %>
          <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :preference, :class => "control-label" %>
          </br>
            <%= f.select(:preference, options_for_select(@preferences.collect { |r| [r[0].humanize, r[0]] }, selected: @sale_contact.preference), {}) %>
          <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>

        <%= f.fields_for(:phone_numbers) do |phone| %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= phone.label :number, "Phone Number", :class => "control-label" %>
            </br>
              <%= phone.text_field :number, :placeholder => "Enter phone number (optional)" %>
              <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <%= phone.hidden_field :key_contact_id %>
            </div>
        <% end %>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.hidden_field :sales_opportunity_id, :value => @sales_opportunity.id %>
        </div>
          <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-success", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }%>
    <% end %>
```

And from my sale_contact_controller new action:

```
  def new
   @sale_contact = SaleContact.new
   @sale_contact.phone_numbers.build
   @sales_opportunity = SalesOpportunity.find(params[:sales_opportunity_id])
   @company = @sales_opportunity.company
   @roles = SaleContact.roles
   @preferences = SaleContact.preferences
   render :modal_form
  end

   def sale_contact_params
     params.require(:sale_contact).permit(:key_contact_id, :sales_opportunity_id, :role, :preference, phone_numbers_attributes: [:number, :id])
    end
```

I run a javascript snippet when the modal is being retrieved via AJAX or the key_contact select dropdown changes to bring in the key_contact_id to the phone_numbers_attributes; if I don't do that I get a 422 unprocessable entity error for not sending through my key_contact_id.

Using this setup the modal pops into view and has the correct fields (both for sale_contact and phone_number), but will not save either of these models - I get a 500 error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms

ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection (Cannot modify association 'SaleContact#phone_numbers' because the source reflection class 'PhoneNumber' is associated to 'KeyContact' via :has_many.):
  app/controllers/sale_contacts_controller.rb:50:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/sale_contacts_controller.rb:49:in `create'
```

I've tried other methods, such as setting the key_contact_id in the sale_contact create method, but I get the same result. I can't work out why this setup complains when I don't pass a key_contact_id (422 error) and complains when I do (500 internal server error as the key_contact_id is being set internally by the rails associations).

What does Rails want me to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my form, but I was able to get passed it by using nested field_for tags

**Proposal.rb**

```
has_many :proposal_section_reviews, :through => :proposal_review_status
has_one :proposal_review_status, :dependent => :destroy
attr_accessible :proposal_review_status_attributes, :proposal_review_status_attributes, :proposal_section_reviews_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :proposal_review_status, :proposal_section_reviews
```

**ProposalSectionReview.rb**

```
belongs_to :proposal_review_status
```

**ProposalReviewStatus.rb**

```
has_many :proposal_section_reviews, :dependent => :destroy
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for proposal do |f|
  = f.fields_for :proposal_review_status do |ff|
    = ff.fields_for :proposal_section_reviews
```

So in your instance I would try

```
<%= f.fields_for(:key_contact) do |key| %>
    <%= key.fields_for(:phone_numbers) do |phone| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= phone.label :number, "Phone Number", :class => "control-label" %>
        </br>
          <%= phone.text_field :number, :placeholder => "Enter phone number (optional)" %>
          <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= phone.hidden_field :key_contact_id %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps